# Converting this bitshift from C to Rust

Tags: c, rust

I'm trying to convert this C code:

```
  data[0] = 0x4B;
  data[1] = (addr>>16) & 0xFF;     // A23-A16
  data[2] = (addr>>8) & 0xFF;      // A15-A08
  data[3] = addr & 0xFF;           // A07-A00
```

To Rust. This is what I did:

```
    data[0] = 0x4B;
    data[1] = ((address>>16) & 0xFF) as u8;     // A23-A16
    data[2] = ((address>>8) & 0xFF) as u8;      // A15-A08
    data[3] = (address & 0xFF) as u8;           // A07-A00
```

How do I know that this is always safe and that produces the same results?

Comment: Couldn't you write some tests if it's not clear to you if it is safe or not?

Comment: There's only ~24 million possible addresses here, so testing them all will take only a few hundred milliseconds. I think you'll find this is fine. In a real test you'd only check boundary conditions, like `0xFFFFFFFF` and `0x00000000` as well as `0x12345678` to test endian issues.

Comment: If you know it works in C, you could mechanically transform the code to Rust, replace addr by address and semicolon to as u8 semicolon for the last three. That should provide some confidence if you know the semantics of Rust.